# Get header value from azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am able to get header value from an Azure function is JS using the following:

```
module.exports = async function (context, eventHubMessages) {
    context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array ${eventHubMessages}`);
    const product = context.bindingData.propertiesArray[0].productFilter;
}
```

How do I get the value of productFilter in an Azure function in C#.

```
 public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("{EventHubName}", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] string myEventHubMessage, Binder binder, ILogger log)
            {
                var parsedMessage = JToken.Parse(Convert.ToString(myEventHubMessage));
 DeviceInfo msg = parsedMessage.ToObject<DeviceInfo>();
var deviceId = msg.deviceId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading your message as `EventData` as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---c-example)

```
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
...

    public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("{EventHubName}", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] EventData myEventHubMessage, Binder binder, ILogger log)
```